# How to create a dynamic table in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, uitableview, visual-studio-2013, tableview

I want to make a table similar to a UITableView in iOS. How can I do this in visual studio using GUI and C#? I am using a Windows Form.

I tried searching online but I couldn't find any tutorials.

Also, I'm new to C# so sorry if it's an easy solution.

Comment: Are you looking for a DataGridView?

Comment: @Florian Schmidinger Yes! Also, is it possible to use Parse.com to populate the DataGridView?

Comment: In the long run i bet you will be much happier with wpf though

Comment: No clue about parse.com to be honest

Comment: Isn't this for mobile apps?

Comment: Ok...what's wpf? (Sorry if it's a dum question)

Comment: Windows Presentation Foundation... a far more flexible framework for UI Development

Comment: Ok...I'll look into it. Thanks! Does it work for desktop apps?

Comment: Yes ... it uses xaml ... and xaml is also present in phone app development as well as desktop apps

Comment: Ill give you an example...

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we have a class:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public string FirstValue { get; set; }
    public string SecondValue { get; set; }
}
```

And a Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication13.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="LightBlue">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Background="LightBlue">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstValue}" Background="Brown"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SecondValue}" Background="Green"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private IEnumerable<SomeClass> datasource;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        datasource = new[]
        {
            new SomeClass{FirstValue = "some", SecondValue = "another"},
            new SomeClass{FirstValue = "more",SecondValue = "yet another"}
        };
        this.DataContext = datasource;
    }
}
```

The result would be:

[image: Demo]

Just to demonstrate how easy WPF is.

Comment: Ok thanks for all your help. Just one question xaml is responsible for the UI and the code (C#) is to do everything else?

Comment: xaml handles UI and the databinding... you could also define objects in xaml but these would be static (which in some cases is ok too)... the design principle wpf works best with is MVVM ... you build up a view model the UI binds to... you can also define commands in the ViewModel... commands implement the ICommand interface... the clear advantage is that you have a clear line between visualisation and the buisness model...

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained

Comment: It may seem a bit much to learn at first but in the long run you get monstrous UI projects done in no time once you get how it works